# String concatenation in JSP EL, inside a function

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How can I do a concatenation like this in EL

```
<c:out value="${r:urlEncode(game.index+'/?=')}" />
```

This doesn't work because it wants to add game.index and '/?=' as numbers, which would be rather silly.

I've also tried this, which doesn't work either:

```
<c:out value="${r:urlEncode(${game.index}/?=)}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible with EL. In EL, the `+` is exclusively a numerical (sum) operator.

Use `<c:set>` beforehand.

```
<c:set var="url" value="${game.index}/?=" />
<c:out value="${r:urlEncode(url)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the function `r:urlEncode` does, you may be able to use an expression like:

```
${r:urlEncode(game.index)}${r:urlEncode('/?=')}
```